# Extbase view variable not getting

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

```
/**
 * New post form
 * @param  \Vendor\My\Domain\Model\Post|null $newPost New post
 * @return void
 * @dontvalidate $newPost
 */
public function newAction(\Vendor\My\Domain\Model\Post $newPost = NULL) {
    $this->view->assign('test', 'hello');
    $this->view->assign('categoryList', $this->categoryRepository->findAllByBlog(0));
    $this->view->assign('postObject', $newPost);
}

public function editAction() {
    $this->view->assign('categoryList', $this->categoryRepository->findAllByBlog(0));
    $postObject = $this->postRepository->findOneByUid($this->request->getArgument('id'));
    $this->view->assign('postObject', $postObject);

}
```

this is my script and my problem is that I have a categoryList array, its is only getting in edit view. I want to use that category list on newaction. When I tried to foreach that array in new action view file it is getting empty. and i can get it after saving the postObject. Any idea about this particular problem? and variable test from newaction also not visible in the newAction Template file.

Am using Typo3 7.6.11

Comment: Dumb question: do you clear the T3 cache after your changes? What do you see with `<f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>`?

Comment: Yes, tried everything. I can see those variables only in controller action, its get unset in between view and action.

Comment: Are you accessing these variables in a template or in partial? In second case it may happen, that you don't pass all the variables via `arguments` to a partial.

Comment: mate, in my question you can see new, and editAction, both are using the same template only the edit,add label is changing, and the i'm using the partial, and passing all arguments, those values are getting correctly on edit view(both template and partial), but  when rendering that view from newAction its not working.

Answer (score 3):

Declare arguments you want to receive, as arguments for your controller action. Reference this argument name correctly in Fluid templates when you build links to your controller action. Do not access arguments from the Request directly. Add correct PDPdoc comments for it, too.

Basically: do the correct thing with your arguments instead of bypassing the framework. This advise applies to anything you do in Extbase.

NB: New and Edit actions should never, ever share the same template (this further indicates you bypass the framework's expected behavior). Create and New, yes. But not New and Edit. If necessary, put the form *fields* in a partial and the form itself in separate templates so you can control the action building and object/object-name setup correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If a `$this->***Repository` method returns `NULL`, it may be that the repository had no `StoragePid` defined.

Make sure both `newAction` and `editAction` have the same storagePid defined in TypoScript or your Backend Plugin Settings (Flexform).

The TypoScript for this would look something like this:

```
plugin.tx_extension.persistence.storagePid = 100
```